# how to use registerPrefixes() methode in autload.php using Symfony 2.2.1

Tags: symfony, autoload

i'm trying to use registerPrefixes() in my app/autoload.php but i get the folowing error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' 
not found in C:\wamp\www\ProjetJidal\app\autoload.php on line 6
```

Here is my autoload.php:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Html2Pdf_'        => __DIR__.'/../vendor/html2pdf/lib',
));

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

i appreciate any help thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing it that way in the past i have just used the unofficial port for composer compatibility.

```
php composer.phar require "ensepar/html2pdf":"dev-master"
```

This command will update your composer.json and install the needed lib and then the autoload.php doesnt have to be updated at all it will be loaded automatically.